# How to add Mobile_Detect.php in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to add Mobile_Detect.php in prestashop 1.7. I tried to override FrontController.php 
according to this post
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224983-need-help-including-class-to-detect-mobile-phones/

but no class added in tpl file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use prestashop default device detect functionality :

get device :

```
Context::getContext()->getDevice();
```

Check Mobile :

```
Context::getContext()->isMobile();
```

Check Tablet:

```
Context::getContext()->isTablet();
```

You can find the prestashop  default class: 
prestashop_root_path/classes/Context.php

Comment: Can I use this in tpl file

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.when i print {Context::getContext()->getDevice();} this return 1 not device name. Also I want to know is there any way to know viewport size in prestashop tpl.

Comment: prestashop_root_path/classes/Context.php open this file and read the class constant for device identification number you can find there.

Comment: Is there any way to know viewport size in prestashop tpl ?

Comment: you have to need assign first then you can access from TPL.

Comment: I am unable to write the code in smarty, please advice.